# jquery validation plugin not working

Tags: jquery, validation

jQuery validation plugin doesn't seem to work with my code. The text fields are present in a table wrapped inside a form. This is a dynamic form.

```
$('#buttonID').live('click', function(event) {

        $('#formID').validate({
          rules: {
                firstName: "required",
                lastName: "required",
                phoneNum: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                pword: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7
                },
                cpword: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7,
                    equalTo: "#pword"
                },
                emailId: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                firstName: "Please enter firstname",
                lastName: "Please enter lastname",
                phoneNum: "Please provide a phone number",              
                pword: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 7 characters long"
                },
                cpword: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 7 characters long",
                    equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                },
                emailId: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }

        });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the code where I create a form on button click:

```
function createNewUser(event){
    //clear all the divs
                    if ($("#srchResults").length > 0){                  
                            $('#srchResults').empty();
                    }
        var htmlTable;

                    htmlTable = '<form id="userAttrC">';
                    htmlTable += '<table style="border: 0px; width: 91%;" id="createUserTable" class="rec_filters">';
                    htmlTable += '<tr><td>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="submit" id="saveUser" class = "buttons" value="Save" >&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="cancelUser" class = "buttons" value="Cancel" >';
                    htmlTable += '</td></tr>';
                    htmlTable += '<tr>';
                    htmlTable += '<td style="width: 30%; vertical-align: top;">';
                    htmlTable += '</td>';
                    htmlTable += '<td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">';
                    htmlTable += '</td>';
                    htmlTable += '<td style="width: 60%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">';

                    htmlTable += '<b>Personal Information</b><br />';
                    htmlTable += '<hr class="d">';
                    htmlTable += '<label for="salutation">Salutation:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<select id="salutationDD" name="salutation" class="filterselect">';
                    htmlTable += '<option value=""></option>';
                    htmlTable += '<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>';
                    htmlTable += '<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>';
                    htmlTable += '<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option></select><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="fname">First Name:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="fname" id="firstName" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="lname">Last Name:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="lname" id="lastName" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="suffix">Name Suffix:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="suffix" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="email">Email:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="email" id="emailId" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="country">Country:</label>';

                    htmlTable += '<select id="countryDD" name="country" class="filterselect">';

                    //get country list via ajax call
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        async: false,   
                        "error":function() {   
                            alert("error");
                    }});
                    $.getJSON("<url>", 
                    {
                    countries: "1"
                    },
                    function(data) {

                            htmlTable += '<option value=""></option>';

                            for(var i=1; i<data[0].length; i++){               
                                htmlTable += '<option value="'+data[0][i]+'">'+data[0][i]+'</option>';
                            }
                    });
                    htmlTable += '</select><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="phone" id="phoneNum" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="ext">Phone Extension:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="ext" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="cell">Cell Phone:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="cell" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';

                    htmlTable += '<label for="pwd">Password:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="pwd" id="pword" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';
                    htmlTable += '<label for="cpwd">Confirm Password:</label>';
                    htmlTable += '<input type="text" name="cpwd" id="cpword" class="readOnlyIp" value="" /><br />';
                    htmlTable += '</td></tr>';
                    htmlTable += '</table>';
                    htmlTable += '</form>';

     $('#srchResults').append(htmlTable);       
    event.preventDefault();
}
$("#createUser").click(function(event){ createNewUser(event); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the validation rules on the button is ok, especially if on document ready, your form doesn't exist yet,   without seeing your entire page code it's hard to say what the BEST place to do it is though.  Likely in the success handler of your ajax call that loads your form.

anyway, the point is, in your button handler, you need to actaully tell the form to validate! like so:

```
$('#formID').valid();
```

this is what i ussually do:

```
if($('#formId').valid()){
    //do your form posting logic here
}
else{
   //anything special you want to do with an invalid form

}
```

EDIT:

ok, put your $('#FormId').validate() stuff right after:

```
$('#srchResults').append(htmlTable);
```

and then have:

```
 if($('#formId').valid()){
        //do your form posting logic here
    }
    else{
       //anything special you want to do with an invalid form

    }
```

inside this:

```
$('#buttonID').live('click', function(event) {
```

Comment: Hi Patricia, can you be more specific..., the form is dynamically created in the button event handler...

Comment: can we see some more of your code?  like the form html,  and the code that makes the form?

Comment: Hi Patricia, I have updated my post with the form code at the bottom. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to move validation to document ready handler:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formID').validate({...})
});`

Comment: I have to validate the forum upon a button click. That is how I have put the code inside button click handler $('#buttonID').live('click', function(event) { and this is inside $(document).ready handler.
 Thanks.

Comment: @stackoverflowFan your code is the setup not the actual validation.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way the validation plugin works.  You need to set your validation code inside the document.ready() function and then call the `.form()` method in your `onClick`  You can use the `submit:false` option if you don't want the form validated on any form submit event...

Something like this:

```
var _validator;

$(function() {
    _validator = $('#formID').validate({
          onsubmit: false,
          rules: { ... },
          messages: { ... }
    });

    $('#buttonID').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( _validator.form() ) {
            // valid form code
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE :

Working jsFiddle example here :  http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/RQMaV/

Comment: Now I get "validator is undefined" error on line "if ( validator.form() ) { "  , whatelse could be wrong in this code...

Comment: Do I have to use form plugin aswell?

Comment: Hi Shane, I still see same error "_validator is undefined" on the line "if ( _validator.form() ) { ". Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure where your error is from, but I've added a link to this code working in jsFiddle...

Comment: The button click event code is different in my case:   '$('#buttonID').live('click', function(event) {' as the form is dynamically generated. Could this be the problem, please see the form code in my original post. Thanks!

Comment: @stackoverflowFan  If this is what you're doing, I'm going to make a suggestion.  Take all the html from `htmlTable` and place it in an actual `div`  Then use jQueryUI's dialog and open it up on `$("#createUser").click()`  Because all of the html will exist on document.ready, the validation code will work as I've written and you will save the processing time of all that string concatination.

Comment: Your suggestion seems promising, but I do not intend to open any pop-ups. The form is created upon a button click dynamically. That is how I am concatenating html. Did I miss your point? Thanks again!

Comment: @stackoverflowFan  A dialog is not the same as a popup, but if you really must avoid the dialog, you can just use a hidden div in the same way and still avoid all the concatenation which is really really slow... (not to mention a pain to code and maintain)

Comment: Hi Shane, where to put such divs? In $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: @stackoverflowFan  Where ever you need it in the mark up if it's not going to be a dialog.  If a dialog, I just put them at the end of the markup, out of the way...

Answer (score 0):

validation plugin works out with 'name' of the input field  means

```
$('#formID').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: "required"
    }
});
```

inside the rules  we uses the name of the input field not the id
`<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="readOnlyIp" value="" />`
so amke

Answer (score -1):

use `validate()` to create rules for validating fields

the call `valid()` to check if rules are met